# What is difference between tf.variable_scope and variable_scope.variable_scope in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I know what `tf.variable_scope` means as it is clearly stated in the document. But in this [example](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/b10f50ff15944badb7262a207f6628dfa52d6a9d/tensorflow/contrib/rnn/python/kernel_tests/lstm_ops_test.py#L62), there is a `variable_scope.variable_scope`. And seems it has not been covered in the documentation. I wonder what is their difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are the same function. The reason it's prefixed with `variable_scope` (instead of `tf`) in the source code is simply because it is *inside* the tensorflow package, as opposed to *outside* (like you). If you browse around the source code more, you'll notice lots of familiar methods with unfamiliar dot-prefixes like that, and for the same reason.

This is not TensorFlow specific, it is just how one imports packages for files within the source code of a python module. If you're interested in learning more about this concept, look into the meaning of `__init__.py` files and how they're used in python.